# Get rows for each user with early date values

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table structure:

```
consumer_id, signup_date, plan_id, subscription_date
```

It has multiple subscription_dates for the same consumer_id.

What I need in the result is all fields with first (min) subscription_date where plan_id is not a specific value.

Without the where clause I tried:

```
select consumer_id, 
       signup_date, 
       plan_id, 
       min(subscription_date) 
from myTable 
Group by consumer_id
```

I get an error stating that

> Column 'signup_date', 'plan_id' is invalid in the select list because
>   it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

But I do not wish to group the results by 'signup_date' or 'plan_id'.

Whatever is the value in the row of 'signup_date' and 'plan_id' after I get the earliest subscription_date for each consumer_id, that is the value I want. How can I write this condition in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```sql
select consumer_id, signup_date, plan_id
     , min(subscription_date) over (partition by consumer_id)
from myTable
```

If needed you can remove unneded rows with your where.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if no other row with same consumer_id but earlier date exists:

```
select consumer_id, 
       signup_date, 
       plan_id, 
       subscription_date
from myTable t1
where not exists (select 1 from myTable t2
                  where t2.consumer_id = t1.consumer_id
                    and t2.subscription_date < t1.subscription_date)
```

Will return both rows if there are two from same, earliest date.

Comment: I don't think that this is the correct answer. Just use a window function. This should solve it.

Comment: @Ionic, my query will return each consumer_id's row(s) with the earliest subscription_date. Isn't that the question?

Comment: Yes, but not exists causes a hash join on each row. On bigger tables this will perform badly.

Comment: np. A window function will generate a group and make a join too afterwards. But it can join it using a hash or a merge join. The subquery can maybe lead to a loop join in a bad case.

Comment: @jarlh: If I wanted to add a where clause 'where plan_id !=1001', where would I add that??

Comment: In the existing WHERE clause: Put AND plan_id !=1001 at the end of the query.

Comment: @Arnab, you mean the query works fine until you add AND plan_id !=1001 ?

Comment: yes, the query works fine but even after adding plan_id !=1001 it shows result with plan_id 1001 but I have added a top 50 just after select at the very top to get limited reults as the table size is huge..., is that by any chance responsible for this.. in the application query top 50 won't be there..

Comment: Perhaps you need to AND plan_id !=1001 to the sub-select's WHERE too?

Answer (score -1):

try this query

```
select a.consumer_id, 
       a.signup_date, 
       a.plan_id,
       b.subcription_date
from myTable as a
join( 
select consumer_id, 
       min(subscription_date)  as subcription_date
from myTable
Group by consumer_id  ) b on a.subcription_date=b.subcription_date and a.consumer_id=b.consumer_id
```

Comment: If I wanted to add a where clause 'where plan_id !=1001', where would I add that

Comment: You are add last in query

Comment: Can you check if the query works, it seems to give error stating ambiguous consumer_id, etc..

Comment: nope.. Incorrect syntax near '.' at 4th line and Incorrect syntax near 'b' in last line..

Answer (score -1):

```
select consumer_id, 
       signup_date, 
       plan_id, 
       min(subscription_date) 
from myTable 
Group by consumer_id, signup_date, plan_id
```

Comment: Not the right answer as he won't group by signup date or plan_id

Comment: But which signup_date and plan_id will you select if there are more than 1 [signup_dates] and [plan_ids] when you only group by [consumer_id]

Comment: Thats the point he could decide in his where clause if needed. Maybe he just wants to display those rows. He can use the window function I've provided and can make the rest on it's own. He hasn't specified very much what he want to do with the other records.

Comment: @FrankCode What I basically wanted was the row with min subscriptiondate for each user